Can conda install libraries based on conditions
I have a machine learning application using pytorch and I'd like to use it either on an EC2 instance (ubuntu) with a GPU or on my macbook with M2 chip
I'm using pytorch and because the hardware is different, I have to install torch==1.11.0+cu113 on my ubuntu instance and the nightly version for my macbook pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
At the moment I have a conda environment file like this
name: my_app
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip=23.3.2
  - python=3.10.13
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt

and my requirements.txt contains the pytorch you manually set depending on which device you are on.
When I create my conda environment i.e conda env create -f conda_env.yml is there a way to automatically download the right pytorch depending on which OS it sees ?
A basic solution would be to have a pair of conda_env_ubuntu.yml and conda_env_macos.yml and a pair of requirements_ubuntu.txt and requirements_macos.txt but I'd rly like to avoid the overhead
Thanks a lot

why do you need toch 1.11 on ubuntu and the pre-release built for macOS?

I don't know of a way to have switches in your yml based on OS. I would go for two seperate yml files, but consider to have paste the content of the requirements.txt into the yml files so you only have two, not four files
